# Network icon in LXPanel

Tags: network-manager, indicator, applet, lxpanel

The network applet in LXPanel apparently isn't using a symbolic icon at <16px as it doesn't respect the color configuration of *any* system theme. Screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31irt.png).

I'm on Lubuntu 16.04.

How can I correct this?
Thanks.